# How to run multiple commands sequentially in nvim?

Tags: neovim, command-line

What I have referenced in my **.zshrc** file:

```
nvim --headless -c 'LspInstall tsserver | qall'
```

This doesn't work. The `qall` is regarded as an argument of `LspInstall` while I didn't mean to. The `LspInstall` will take some time to download the language servers, thus it seems like that I need some pseudo-command like:

```
await LspInstall tsserver then qall
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can use multiple `-c` flags. Does `nvim --headless -c 'LspInstall tsserver' -c 'qall'` work?

Comment: @BLayer: You're awesome :) It works! Sorry for my easy question.

Comment: :) No worries. .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the `LspInstall` user command is configured to take multiple parameters. No matter, you can use multiple `-c` flags, each with their own command(s).

Specifically...

> You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" arguments in a Vim command. They are executed in the order given.  A "-S" argument counts as a "-c" argument as well.

(Source: `:h -c`)

So try...

```
nvim --headless -c 'LspInstall tsserver' -c 'qall'
```

Comment: I'm happy-happy now~

Comment: It is more likely the command wasn’t declared with `-bar`, in which case the bar wont work. Wrapping in execute will, or multiple commands, as you pointed out. (`-nargs=` whatever has nothing to do with bar-handling, in other words.)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution that works if you're running the commands inside a Vim instance (you're not, but the existing answer is already the best solution for your exact circumstances) is to use [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to more specifically delimit the arguments to the `LspInstall` command.

Instead of:

```
:LspInstall tsserver | qall
```

You can use:

```
:execute "LspInstall tsserver" | qall
```

Comment: As I said under the other answer, I suspect `LspInstall` is missing `-bar`